# Django - sort by userprofile field in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I figured out how to get UserProfile information to appear in my admin field thanks to some help from you guys.  Now I want to come up with a way to properly sort those fields.  I'm close.

```
class EmployerProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [EmployerProfileInline, ]
    def company(self):
        return self.get_profile().company
    company.admin_order_field = 'employerprofile'
    list_display = ('username','first_name','last_name',company,'email','password',)
```

This let's me sort the company field from my UserProfile (EmployerProfile) but I have to sort it according to a field in the User.  The User has 'employerprofile' but that's an entire object.  How does django know how to sort on that field?  Is it something I can overwrite in the EmployerProfile class?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to order? The code to the other model would help.

Answer (score 1):

As Honza said, what are you trying to order?

In general, the order in the admin change list page will follow the model's default ordering, or can be specified by ModelAdmin.ordering as a list or tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try using the model__field approach?
As others say we don't know the whole problem, but

```
class Meta:
    ordering = [ "user__fieldname" ]
```

might work (not tested). Provided you have a "user" field which is a ForeignKey and fieldname is present in the foreign model.

So something like:

```
class User( object ):
    fieldname = models.CharField( max_length = 255 )

class Profile( object )
     class Meta:
         ordering = [ "user__fieldname" ]
     user = models.ForeignKey( User )
```